# Angular build not getting deployed to azure in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, angular, visual-studio, azure

I have been working on an Angular project for a while now, I have been running Angular 5 for a while now and I upgraded the project to Angular 6, and hopefully soon to Angular 7. When I try to publish the project to Azure App Service it succesfully builds both .net and angular files. I also deploys the .net build to the server, but for some reason it does not upload the angular build anymore. I haven't changed anything in my csproj, it comes directly from the Angular template from Visual Studio.

With Angular 5 i never had this problem, I then upgraded to 6 and had that issue. Couldn't resolve it, so i created a new project and copied all the files. It worked for a few days, and now it's broken again. I have not made any changed to any file involved with publishing the project.

Here is my csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>

    <!-- Set this to true if you enable server-side prerendering -->
    <BuildServerSideRenderer>false</BuildServerSideRenderer>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CsvHelper" Version="12.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Sendgrid" Version="9.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build --prod" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" Condition="'$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true'" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

The path should be correct because it builds the angular files on that same path and i can find the build files within the dist folder.

Grabbing the files from the build in the output folder and uploading it with ftp manually works, but ofcourse this behaviour is unwanted.

Answer (score 1):

I, too, have this problem. Although I do not yet have a solution I do have a work-around that might be faster/easier than ftp transfer. In visual studio, you can [right click] the 'dist' directory and publish it directly.

This worked for me and is a clue.